# The function of pyFFTW that has exactly same result with FFT of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, fft, fftw, pyfftw

I'm looking for the function of pyFFTW that has exactly same result with FFT of MATLAB.

I already tried with some functions of pyFFTW like bellows.

x is 1D array, type: np.float32

Python 3.5.2:

```
a = fftw.n_byte_align_empty(x.size, 16, 'complex128')
b = fftw.n_byte_align_empty(x.size, 16, 'complex128')
fft_object = fftw.FFTW(a, b)

fft_object(x)
```

or

```
fft_object = fftw.builders.fft(x)

fft_object()
```

MATLAB:

```
fft(x)
```

But, there are a little differences(about 0.000001) by comparison with MATLAB's FFT.

Is there no way to get the exactly same result with MATLAB's FFT??

- Version of python : 3.5.2
- Version of pyFFTW : 0.10.4
- Version of numpy : 1.12.0
- Version of MATLAB : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: no, there is likely no way. Long answer: (1) Matlab uses a custom wisdom file (FFTW uses this to decide how to decompose the FFT). You could try to get them to match by using [`fftw`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html) on the Matlab side and use the same planner on the Python side, but (2) Matlab’s FFTW is compiled using Intel MKL, while your PyFFTW is probably not.

Comment: In general, if your results match to machine precision, they are close enough: if `all(abs(python(:) - matlab(:)) / abs(matlab(:)) < eps(norm(matlab))*100)`, then you can say the relative error between the two are the same to within 100 times machine precision, and that’s good enough for engineering work.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Thank you for response. You're been a big help.

Comment: In the first case, you're planning a `complex128` transform. The `FFTW` object will coerce your `float32` into that array (you can have more precise control over it, but then you need to call the transform manually - read the API). The second case will plan for a `float32` so will be different to the first. I've no idea what Matlab is doing behind the scenes before it calls FFTW. It's more complicated in general to get the fastest transform than just plan and call - alignment for example can make a huge difference. Try the `pyfftw.interfaces` api if you want something that works like Matlab.